# Failure to execute cql script using cqlsh with nested SOURCE on DSE 5.1.2

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have a script I used to execute queries and DDL in DSE 4.8.10.

The script include nested use of the SOURCE command.
E.g.
1.sql

```
USE test;
SOURCE '2.sql'
exit;
```

2.sql

```
SELECT count(1) FROM user;
SOURCE '3.sql';
```

3.sql

```
SELECT count(1) FROM user;
```

When executing this script with DSE 4.8.10 it runs correctly and output

```
cqlsh –f  1.sql
count
--------
 0

(1 rows)

count
--------
 0

(1 rows)
```

Running the same script in DSE 5.1.2.

```
cqlsh –f  1.sql
 count
-------
     0

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key

2.sql:3:DSEShell instance has no attribute 'execution_profiles'
```

The actual issue is that the script in 3.sql is not executed.
I failed to find any useful information on the error
"DSEShell instance has no attribute 'execution_profiles'"

I failed to figure out what are execution_profiles although they are mentioned int the python docs [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html)

Note: I am using python 2.7.7

**Update**
I did some additional investigations

1. With DSE-5.1.2 I switch the off to authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
   authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer, but I am still experiencing the issue
2. With  DSE-5.1.1 it also happens
3. With DSE-5.0.9 it works
4. I failed to reproduce this in Apache Cassandra 3.11.0

**Update 2:** following support ticket we posted for Datastaxs we got a patch for this issue, I guess we should be expecting this to be fixed in the near feature.

Answer (score 0):

As from DSE 5.1.4 this issue was resolved as part of DSP-14494.

See the [5.1.4 release notes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html#RNdse514__514resIss)

DSP-14494:Always define execution_profiles in cqlsh.py.
I tested this with 5.1.4 and the issue was resolved.